# How can I delete all (or any) discussions from my Disqus admin?

Tags: disqus

I put Disqus on my site.

This automatically created discussions and URLs in Disqus admin.

However, I noticed I have some of the URLs have mistakes. There are many discussions; I don't want to edit URLs manually.

I want to **remove all**, for creation new discussions. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the moderation panel, you should see a tab "All" where you can select all your comments and then hit the delete button (see [description](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466238#using-mod-panel)). You can also delete the complete site and all comments on it by following [these instructions](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/471985-how-do-i-remove-my-site-).

BTW: The help section of disqus is not too bad, you may give it a try next time before asking here ;-)

Comment: But it not helped me. I mean the discussions, not comments. Thanks for answer.

Comment: A discussion is just a combination of several comments, so what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Yes you are right. these are combination. But in admin panel  has "Set specific authors for each post, update titles, and close old discussions." Did you understand?

Comment: I understood that you want to delete all "discussions". As those just consist of several comments, I still believe that deleting those comments will produce the result you are searching for. So no, I don't really understand what the problem is right now.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The All tab contains no threads, even though my forum has threads.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: Disqus does not allow you to delete Discussions.

Answer (score 7):

A bit longer answer:

You can delete the whole site with all your discussions and comments, obviously, too.

But if you have some unwanted discussions that you'd like to get rid of, then you can also "merge" the unwanted discussions into one, presumably wanted, using [Disqus "URL mapper feature"](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/912757) from admin->tools panel. This will cause the unwanted "litter" with mistakes be deleted and disappear from your admin view. It is still manual work but with a macro-capable text editor you can process even long lists relatively effectively (been there, seen that ;-)