# Is there a way to delete ALL threads in Disqus?

Tags: disqus

I removed several pages with disqus threads from [my website](https://scitronboy.github.io/), so now in the "latest discussions" section of Disqus for my site, it lists comments which redirect to a 404 (because I removed the pages). So I followed the advice on [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50902/how-can-i-delete-all-or-any-discussions-from-my-disqus-admin) but the comments still show up in the "latest discussions" section.

So is there a way to delete a thread from the "latest discussions" section? Or do I just need to wait until Disqus updates? Also, I might consider deleting my whole disqus site, but if I do that, will I be able to re-create it?

Answer (score 1):

If you close the discussions by using the padlock icon on the discussion view, that may prevent them from showing up in "related discussions".

As for deleting the whole Disqus site and recreating it, there is really nothing stopping you. It's not like Disqus blacklists the domain name for you and all domain future owners as soon as you delete a Disqus "site" (which are not even 1-to-1 correlated with domains, by the way).

Comment: I am not trying to stop them from showing up in "related discussions", but I am trying to stop them from appearing in "latest discussions".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the answer on the Disqus website.

Tell me please, can you edit the discussions from here? http://disqus.com/admin/discussions

There are plenty of help articles on their website, and if you search you might find some relevant information. https://help.disqus.com/ (Search for "latest discussions".)

Like this for example:

https://help.disqus.com/troubleshooting/introducing-the-discussions-editor-and-faq

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, you can edit the discussions from the discussion editor. However, there is no way to delete a discussion so that it does not show up in the "recent discussions" section on a website with Disqus installed. I think this is just a glitch though so I don't think I will be getting any answers anytime soon. BTW, contacting Disqus didn't help much, but I might try it again.

Comment: Yeah contacting them seems best bet. I hope they sort you out!